# Python script crashes when running Mayavi's mri example

Tags: python, data-visualization, scientific-computing, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

This example is from Mayavi Documentation [Mri Example](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_mri.html#example-mri), and I haven't done any changes.

```
import os
if not os.path.exists('MRbrain.tar.gz'):
    # Download the data
    try:
        from urllib import urlopen
    except ImportError:
        from urllib.request import urlopen
    print("Downloading data, Please Wait (7.8MB)")
    opener = urlopen(
                'http://graphics.stanford.edu/data/voldata/MRbrain.tar.gz')
    open('MRbrain.tar.gz', 'wb').write(opener.read())

# Extract the data
import tarfile
tar_file = tarfile.open('MRbrain.tar.gz')
try:
    os.mkdir('mri_data')
except:
    pass
tar_file.extractall('mri_data')
tar_file.close()


### Read the data in a numpy 3D array #########################################
import numpy as np
data = np.array([np.fromfile(os.path.join('mri_data', 'MRbrain.%i' % i),
                                        dtype='>u2') for i in range(1, 110)])
data.shape = (109, 256, 256)
data = data.T

# Display the data ############################################################
from mayavi import mlab

mlab.figure(bgcolor=(0, 0, 0), size=(400, 400))

src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(data)
# Our data is not equally spaced in all directions:
src.spacing = [1, 1, 1.5]
src.update_image_data = True


# Extract some inner structures: the ventricles and the inter-hemisphere
# fibers. We define a volume of interest (VOI) that restricts the
# iso-surfaces to the inner of the brain. We do this with the ExtractGrid
# filter.
blur = mlab.pipeline.user_defined(src, filter='ImageGaussianSmooth')
voi = mlab.pipeline.extract_grid(blur) #########crashes
voi.set(x_min=125, x_max=193, y_min=92, y_max=125, z_min=34, z_max=75)

mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(voi, contours=[1610, 2480], colormap='Spectral')

# Add two cut planes to show the raw MRI data. We use a threshold filter
# to remove cut the planes outside the brain.
thr = mlab.pipeline.threshold(src, low=1120)
cut_plane = mlab.pipeline.scalar_cut_plane(thr,
                                plane_orientation='y_axes',
                                colormap='black-white',
                                vmin=1400,
                                vmax=2600)
cut_plane.implicit_plane.origin = (136, 111.5, 82)
cut_plane.implicit_plane.widget.enabled = False

cut_plane2 = mlab.pipeline.scalar_cut_plane(thr,
                                plane_orientation='z_axes',
                                colormap='black-white',
                                vmin=1400,
                                vmax=2600)
cut_plane2.implicit_plane.origin = (136, 111.5, 82)
cut_plane2.implicit_plane.widget.enabled = False

# Extract two views of the outside surface. We need to define VOIs in
# order to leave out a cut in the head.
voi2 = mlab.pipeline.extract_grid(src)
voi2.set(y_min=112)
outer = mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(voi2, contours=[1776, ],
                                        color=(0.8, 0.7, 0.6))

voi3 = mlab.pipeline.extract_grid(src)
voi3.set(y_max=112, z_max=53)
outer3 = mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(voi3, contours=[1776, ],
                                         color=(0.8, 0.7, 0.6))


mlab.view(-125, 54, 326, (145.5, 138, 66.5))
mlab.roll(-175)

mlab.show()

import shutil
shutil.rmtree('mri_data')
```

When it runs
`voi = mlab.pipeline.extract_grid(blur)`
, it just crashes with no erro messages. I have installed
Python3.6 and mayavi4.5.0+vtk7.1 and numpy1.12.1+mkl. Could you tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: What error message do you get?  Which line?

Comment: Is it a python exception or a proper crash (e.g. SIGSEGV)? If its the former please add the full traceback.

Comment: @Paul Rooney. I have updated my question, thx. When it runs 'voi = mlab.pipeline.extract_grid(blur)' , it just crashes with no erro messages.

Comment: @Turix. I have updated my question, thx. When it runs 'voi = mlab.pipeline.extract_grid(blur)' , it just crashes with no erro messages.

Comment: Then your environment is hiding an exception from you. I suggest either running the program outside of your environment (enthought?) or run it under a debugger and see where the problem occurs.

Comment: @Paul Rooney I use Pycharm to debug it and  it just crashes with no error messages,. I'm very confused.

Comment: If there is no error message how do you know it's crashed? Perhaps it just ran and exited very quickly. Check you've called whatever function it is that blocks and runs the guy. Also those imports are a bit weird. I can understand it for the urllib but for the others I'd just put all the imports at the top.